# How to add placeholder and change form field label simultaneously in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to change the field label in django form and also want to add a place holder but when I set a placeholder attribute, field label doesn't work and shows the default field label "work_or_study" instead of "Bio". 
here is the code:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
date_of_birth=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'y-m-d'}))
work_or_study=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'something interesting about you'}))
class Meta:
    model= Profile
    labels = {"work_or_study":"Bio"}
    fields = ('date_of_birth','work_or_study')
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix the label change this

```
work_or_study=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'something interesting about you'}))
```

to

```
work_or_study=forms.CharField(label="Bio", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'something interesting about you'}))
```

and delete the labels list in the Meta